# No layout preview visible after setting app theme to material design and using material button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-design-library

I am using the material design as my app theme, but due to this, there is some issue while viewing the layout preview in android studio. There is no preview displayed but when I run the code I am able to view the design on the device.

The issue is mainly because of the material button I have used. when I comment the button code the preview is shown, but when I uncomment the code and refresh the layout the preview is again not visible.

Below is the code od how I have applied the material theme to my app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Below is the Code I have used in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            style="@style/text_sui_generis"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border_shadow"
            android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="20dp"
                   android:layout_height="20dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                   android:id="@+id/locationImage"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/locationImage"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signin_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            style="@style/buttonCustomFont"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlSpinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems problem lies in your custom style of material button can you please provide that `@style/buttonCustomFont` style

Comment: Sure Sudheer, here is the code for the same <style name="buttonCustomFont"> <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sui_generis</item> <item name="android:textColor">@color/textSecondary</item> <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item> </style>

Comment: Show your  style file=buttonCustomFont.xml

Comment: the above-mentioned code is what I am using in buttonCustomFont.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is the issue of Android Studio.

I also have faced this issue in Android Studio 3.4.2 stable version. In this stable version, the design preview is not working when set App theme as "Theme.MaterialComponents.*"

The design preview is working fine with beta "Android Studio 3.5 RC 1"

Try downloading the latest beta version.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Force Refresh Layout Option in Design Preview

[image]

Comment: I tried to use the Force Layout Option but it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

You don't wrote `buttonCustomFont` in style i think

Remove this line and refresh preview

```
 style="@style/buttonCustomFont"
```

Full code

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/signin_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlSpinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>
```

Comment: here is the code for that I have used to style the button and it has been applied to it when I view it on the device, but even after removing the line the view is still not visible for preview <style name="buttonCustomFont">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sui_generis</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    </style>